# Neo4j cypher get status updates with 'total likes' and 'has liked'

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the following query to get user status updates and total likes each have received:

```
MATCH (n:user {username: "pewpewlasers"})-[:STATUSUPDATE|:NEXT*]->(o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:user)-[x:LIKED]->(o)
RETURN n, o, COUNT(p) AS totallikes
ORDER BY o.date DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

This works great, but now I want to also get information on whether a particular user has liked these status updates (to implement 'unlike' feature). I tried the following and it is giving me big (wrong) numbers, even the `totallikes`

```
MATCH (n:user {username: "pewpewlasers"})-[:STATUSUPDATE|:NEXT*]->(o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:user)-[:LIKED]->(o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (q:user {username: "anotherUser"})-[:LIKED]->(o)
RETURN n, o, COUNT(p) AS totallikes, COUNT(q) AS hasLiked
ORDER BY o.date DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 10
```

EDIT: The graph looks like the following (orange nodes -> user nodes, gray nodes -> status update nodes):
[image: Orange represent user nodes, gray represents status update nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses are essentially identical, except for the `username` qualification in the second one. Therefore, logically, it should be possible for a single relationship to match both clauses. However, [according to the neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html):

> While pattern matching, Cypher makes sure to not include matches where
>   the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single
>   pattern.

It is possible that this is causing the number of matches to be too low.

Does the following work better for you?

[EDITED]

```
MATCH (n:user {username: "pewpewlasers"})-[:STATUSUPDATE|:NEXT*]->(o)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:user)-[:LIKED]->(o)
WITH n, o, COLLECT(p) AS cp
RETURN n, o, length(cp) AS totallikes, length(filter(x IN cp WHERE x.username="anotherUser")) AS hasLiked
ORDER BY o.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: hasLiked is actually outputting the same number as totallikes regardless of `p.username`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "regardless of `p.username`"? Also, are there actually more than 1 `user` who `LIKED` the same `o`?

Comment: Hi, yes there could be more users liking the same `o`. `o` is a status update node which could have many likes. `totallikes` and `hasLiked` are giving same values even when `anotherUser` is changed.

Comment: I have added a picture to the question. Hopefully makes it clearer.

Comment: According to your picture, there are no nodes liked by more than one other node. 9 and 10 are liked only by 5; and 12, 22, and 31 are liked only by 0. With this graph, one should expect that `totallikes` and `hasliked` would be identical. (I presume 0 is "pewpewlasers")

Comment: I think you are confusing it a bit. `hasLiked` must only consider likes by that particular user. If you take node 5, it has liked 2 posts, hasLiked should ignore the remaining 3 likes from node 0... so no, even in this case totallikes must be different from hasliked

Comment: Yes, works (haven't yet checked the performance though). Thanks a lot for your help.